# Comparing two strings - boolean

Tags: java

How would you complete the method called c`ompareTwoStrings()` which takes two `Strings` and one `boolean` as input. If the boolean is true, this method compares the first two Strings, ignoring case considerations (uppercase/lowercase). Two Strings are considered equal ignoring case if they are of the same length, and corresponding characters in the two Strings are equal ignoring case.

If the boolean is false, this method should compare two Strings and return true if the first String represents the same sequence of characters as the second String, otherwise false.

Note: `compareTwoStrings("HELLO", "", false)` should return false

I attempted to use `a.equals(b)` however that fails to ignore uppercase/lowercase

Comment: We don't mind helping with repeated homework questions, but for goodness sake, show the least amount of self-effort.

Comment: Here is the question your classmate posted earlier, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852978/comparing-two-strings-with-boolean

Comment: if (isIgnoreCase == false){
    return false;
    }

    else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)){ 
    return true ; 
    } 
    else{ 
    return false ; 
    }

Answer (score 6):

```
private static boolean compareTwoStrings(String string, String string2, boolean ignoreCase) {
    return ignoreCase ? string.equalsIgnoreCase(string2) : string.equals(string2);
}
```

Comment: +1 perfect. Welcome to stackoverflow. A very nice start.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying `a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)` within your method where `a.equals(b)` fails.

`equalsIgnoreCase` will match two strings ignoring their case. So for instance, "Ben Barkay" will match "ben barkay" or "beN barkaY" but not "ben_barkay" or "b3n barkay"